# Preg_replace for url and download links

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

Right now i am using

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```

for replacing url text with links. But, it doesn't works with + and ~ symbols in url. Can anyone figure it out what have to be done over here.

And also 
i want its modified version for download links which replace url text with Download.

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">Download</a>', $content);
```

for

```
 $fields=array('.exe','.mp3','.pdf','.rar','.doc','.jar','.ppt','.xls','.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.mp4','.avi','.mkv','.flv','.3gp','.mms','.sis','.sisx','.jad','.mdi','.qcp');
```

extensions.

e.g.,
http://www.abc.com/song1.mp3

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/song1.mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

http://www.abc.com?id=1&query=preg+replace

```
 <a href="http://www.abc.com?id=1&query=preg+replace" target="_blank">http://www.abc.com?id=1&query=preg+replace</a>
```

Comment: still it doesn't include # in the url. And i want the common preg_replace for download link as well as for normal url link or a methodology so that i can apply both url and download preg_replace on same text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for links with + and ~:

```
@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?((/[\w/_\.%\-+~]*)?(\?\S+)?)?)@
```

And this for your downloads:

```
@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?/[\w/_\.%\-+~]+(\.exe|\.mp3|\.pdf|\.rar|\.doc|\.jar|\.ppt|\.xls|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.mp4|\.avi|\.mkv|\.flv|\.3gp|\.mms|\.sis|\.sisx|\.jad|\.mdi|\.qcp)(\?\S+)?)@
```

Here you can test them:
http://regexr.com?2vdij
http://regexr.com?2vdia

**EDIT:**

Now I see your problem with the link http://www.abc.com?id=1&query=preg+replace - there is a parentheses flaw in your first regexp. I have corrected my first example!

Comment: still it doesn't include # in the url. And i want the common preg_replace for download link or a methodology so that i can apply both url and download preg_replace on same text.

Answer (score 1):

To add `~` change `(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)` to `(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-~]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)`

Answer (score 1):

Supposed that the var `$content` is a text like this:

```
<a href="http://somelink/" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

you can use this code:

```
$content = preg_replace('!<a href="([^\"]+)" target="_blank">[^<]+</a>!', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```